# Why is the if statement not working after random boolean?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

Why is the `if` statement line an error? im trying to get an `if` statement after a random boolean. is this possible?

```
package lieDetector;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LieDetector {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type In a Question here");
        String q1 = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Insert Answer here");
        String a1 = scanner.nextLine();

    }
    public boolean getRandomBoolean() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextBoolean();
        if (random.boolean == true);
        System.out.println("you are telling the truth");
    }
}
```

Comment: `return random.nextBoolean();`?

Comment: `return random.nextBoolean();` this will end the method call right there...

Comment: And this code won't compile either

Comment: you got an error because you wrote code that can never be called. So you are going to get an error along the lines of "Unreachable code"

Answer (score 0):

Two issues (with `getRandomBoolean`)

1. `return random.nextBoolean();` will cause the code to return to the call immediately
2. `random.boolean` is an invalid statement, `Random` doesn't have a `boolean` field named `boolean`, it's actually impossible
3. The `;` at the end of `if (random.boolean == true);` would short circuit the statement (if it could compile), executing the very next line of code regardless of the result of the `if` statement.  This is why we encourage the use of `{...}` blocks with `if` statements, even if they are a single line, it's actually easier to read as well (IMHO)

Instead, lets get the result of `random.nextBoolean()`, use that in the `if` statement, then `return` it, for example...

```
public boolean getRandomBoolean() {
    Random random = new Random();
    boolean value = random.nextBoolean();
    if (value) {
        System.out.println("you are telling the truth");
    }
    return value;
}
```

> when i replace it with your code it terminates after i input the answer. any ideas?

You need to actually call the method (`getRandomBoolean`) and maybe use it's return value, for example

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LieDetector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LieDetector lieDetector = new LieDetector();
        lieDetector.runTest();
    }

    public void runTest() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type In a Question here");
        String q1 = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Insert Answer here");
        String a1 = scanner.nextLine();

        if (getRandomBoolean()) {
            System.out.println("you are telling the truth");
        }
    }

    public boolean getRandomBoolean() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

You might like to have a look at [Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) for more details

Comment: when i replace it with your code (sorry im only 12, still a noob) it terminates after i input the answer. any ideas?

Comment: You're not actually calling the method

Comment: so would i say System.out.println(value) to call it? sorry

Comment: No, check update, you would need an instance of `LieDetector` before you could call the `getRandomBoolean` method, which returns a `boolean` value, which you can use to make decisions with

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the if statement line an error?

Because `Random` doesn't provide a field called `boolean`. (`random.boolean`...)

> im trying to get an if statement after a random boolean. is this possible?

Yes, but you need proper syntax.

```
return random.nextBoolean();
```

this line will end your method call. No code directly below it in the same method will execute.

```
public boolean getRandomBoolean() {
    Random random = new Random();
    boolean myRandomBoolean = random.nextBoolean(); // instead, assign the next random boolean to a variable
    if (myRandomBoolean) { // remove the semicolon and replace with {
        System.out.println("you are telling the truth");
    }

    return myRandomBoolean; // return the value at the end of the method
}
```

Lastly, you need to call this method it in your `main` method... You don't currently have anything actually calling this method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type In a Question here");
    String q1 = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Insert Answer here");
    String a1 = scanner.nextLine();

    LieDetector lieDetector = new LieDetector();
    boolean truth = lieDetector.getRandomBoolean();
    // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided inline comments for your method

```
public boolean getRandomBoolean() {
  // Create Random Generator:
  Random random = new Random();
  // generate a random boolean, stop running remainder, and return boolean
  return random.nextBoolean();
  // Whatever follows will never execute. javac and editor will
  // flag such dead code as an error.
  // If random value is true, then do nothing. Empty ';' = Do-Nothing
  if (random.boolean == true);
  // Always print "You are telling the truth"
  System.out.println("you are telling the truth");
}
```

Now I am going to take a leap of faith in guessing how you wanted it to run:

```
public boolean getRandomBoolean() {
  Random random = new Random();
  boolean randomBoolean = random.nextBoolean();
  if (randomBoolean) {
    System.out.println("you are telling the truth");
  }
  return randomBoolean;
}
```

Comment: Not the DV, but it won't compile

Comment: ah - good catch. Also looks like one was just a little earlier with the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible.

The problems in your code:

You put the `if` statement in a wrong place and add a semicolon(`;`) after it. If you put `return` before any statement in a method, the statement will become **unreachable**. And if you put a semicolon after `if`, it will be **ignored**.

Also, there is no field called `boolean` under `Random` class

This may be the code you want:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LieDetector
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type In a Question here");
        String q1 = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Insert Answer here");
        String a1 = scanner.nextLine();

        if (getRandomBoolean())
          System.out.println("You are telling the truth");
    }

    public static boolean getRandomBoolean()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

BTW, you don't need `==` when you test a boolean. `boolean` and `boolean == true` are the same